# Push 4 bits into an int in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, integer, bit-manipulation

For an implementation of a SPN crypografic feature (studies related) I'm trying to push 4bits into an int.
I can pinpoint the mistake, but I don't know how to fix it (might stared too long at it for now).

```
private int applySBox(int a, boolean inverse, boolean verbose) {
    // split int (16 bit) into parts of 4 bit keeping the right order
    int[] parts = new int[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        parts[4 - i - 1] = a & 0b1111;
        a = a >> 4;
    }

    // Apply the SBox to each 4 bit
    // E.g. 1101 traverse (enc) = 1001, inverse (dec) = 0010
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(inverse) {
            parts[i] = sbox.inverse(parts[i]);
        } else {
            parts[i] = sbox.traverse(parts[i]);
        }
    }

    int result = 0;
    // put back together
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        result = parts[i] & 0b1111;
        // TODO: Reassigning does not help here, needs shift and &
        result = result << 4;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Before the SBox I might get a value of `1100111011001111` as cipher text.
In the split portion I get something like this:

```
Fragment[0]: 0001100011110000
Round Value: 0001100011110000
Current key: 1101011000111111
New r Value: 1100111011001111
---
Before SBox: 1100_1110_1100_1111
Part[0] before SBox: 1100
Part[1] before SBox: 1110
Part[2] before SBox: 1100
Part[3] before SBox: 1111
Part[0] after SBox: 1011
Part[1] after SBox: 0000
Part[2] after SBox: 1011
Part[3] after SBox: 0101
```

I know this is correct based on the defintion of the SBox I have to use.
This would mean, that in order to get the result I have to push parts 0 to 3 pack into one int `1011_0000_1011_0101` and it would be the correct result.
I can clearly see that it won't work because I always overwrite the result with `result = parts[i] & 0b1111;` I just can't seem to find a fix.
How can I push an int[] array each int with 4 bits worth of data in the order from 0 to 3 into the int result containing 16 bit of data?

Comment: Convert it to a string and use Integer.parseInt(string, 2)

Comment: @Ryan bad idea, you can make it work (pitfall: the parts, in string form, must contain exactly 4 bits, padded with leading zeroes if necessary) but it wouldn't be any simpler than recombining the parts with bit-manipulation, just more obfuscated really. Certainly this operation can be *thought of* as concatenating strings, but that's not a good way to actually do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean:

```java
result = (result << 4) | parts[i];
```

or, same thing written differently:

```java
result |= parts[i] << (4 * (4-i));
```

If so then, yes, you stared too long at the screen and "got square eyes" as they say!

---

Update: Since OP implies it's OK to lock-in four parts. Here's an untested one-liner for the `traverse` variant:

```java
return sbox.traverse(a & 0b1111) 
  | sbox.traverse(a >> 4 & 0b1111) << 4
  | sbox.traverse(a >> 8 & 0b1111) << 8
  | sbox.traverse(a >> 12 & 0b1111) << 12
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain OP means neither one of these. `parts` is 4 4-bit values and OP just wants to return `(parts[0] << 12) | (parts[1] << 8) | (parts[2] << 4) | parts[3]`. So `&` should be `|` according to my understanding.

Comment: Oops! That was a terrible mistake :)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk thank you for this input, this is exactly what I searched for!

Comment: Well, if you only ever ever have 4 parts then you don't need that `int[] parts` at all :)

Answer (score 2):

If you shift the bits to the left then the rightmost bits fill up with zeros. So then you need to XOR or OR the results into place.

Try and replace

```
result = parts[i] & 0b1111;
```

with

```
result ^= parts[i] & 0b1111;
```

or

```
result |= parts[i] & 0b1111;
```

otherwise you are simply reassigning the value and delete the previous 4 bit blocks.